# Android Volley async loader on Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3, android-volley

I had a working setup with volley loading images in the app from a AWS S3 server.

Then I created a new bucket to host images for a staging server and migrated all the images into that folder. The staging server is setup to output the updated url to the app.

i.e.
http://production.s3.amazonaws.com/images/thumb/123_myfile.jpg?1400162334
became
http://staging.s3.amazonaws.com/images/thumb/123_myfile.jpg?1400162334

I can load the image in the new bucket from iOS application or any browser in the office, but the Android application does not load any image from that bucket.

It will still load a image if I hardcode the production bucket url or any other image on the internet, just not any from the new bucket.  Nothing is throwing out any error messages either.

The permissions on the two buckets are pretty much identical, the only difference between the two buckets is that one is under region, one says Oregon and the other says US Standard.

Any ideas

Comment: You have to debug your code and see where it hangs. Do you get a correct response? Try putting a break point at your listener for the image request.

Comment: The log shows s3 unknown host exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found the problem.

S3 allows you to append your bucket name in different places in the url, therefore you can access the same image from these two different urls on the browser

http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/images/thumb/image_name.png (domain_url)

or

http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/images/thumb/image_name.png (path_url)

It works fine in both methods if the bucket name is all characters. However, if using domain_url, the bucket name includes '_' then you will get errors from volley (or java).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the accepted answer:

The reason for this error is the bucket name. Amazon s3 discourages using "_" in the bucket name.

Naming conventions for the s3 Bucket name [Bucket Naming Conventions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)